# libGDX strange FPS drop and debugging

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm making game in Android with libGDX, and use this features of game engine:

- Sounds,music
- TextureAtlas (total number of this obj:2)
- TileMap
- Simple gesture detection
- Good usage of AssetsManager with disposing object after usage.

And I have some strange FPS drops sometimes. 
FPS is normally around 59 and then for second it drops around 39-42,and at that moment game "freezes" a little, so pause between two frames is large.

I don't know what is exactly problem and how to find source of the problem, because I can't disguise it with my debugging skills.

1. I have checked memory allocation, and GC acitivity=> no problem, GC isn't activated at that moment.
2. I've tried method tracking but it can't be useful in tracking the bug, because only tracking uses a lot of resources, and FPS is around 10 when it is started.
3. I go throught my code and try to find problem, but every frame I do same things and there are no reason to FPS drop.

I'm not going to post some code on the post, because I really don't know which part of code can make problems.

I ask you: Do you have smillar expirience with libGDX and how do you solve it, and do you know how can I with debugging tools catch the bug.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are known minor issues with sound and android especially on samsung devices (which is probably what your emulator is).

I suspect it is this that is causing the problem and that if you inspect the frame rate when multiple concurrent sounds are playing that it will drop slightly as you have described.

Ways in which to overcome this as best as you can are too lower the sample rate of your sound/music files as best you can and also to store Music as .mp3 and Sound as .wav.

The reason being that Sound as a wav file skips unnecessary decoding, which happens with .mp3, when sounds are mixed in memory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling things one by one until you see the FPS is stable. Say, commenting out a particle effect, sound explosion, or maybe any game effect one by one. 
Take a look at [libGDX Profiling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Profiling).

- Check if you are making too many draw calls or texture switches.
- Use performance counter on each of your methods in render loop one by one
  and look which one is taking time more than it should.